# Problem with \newcommand and \text

Tags: math-mode, macros, lyx, amsmath

I'm having a problem with `\newcommand`. Below is my LyX document where the first line comes from the "Insert-Latex" command and the second line is using the "Insert-Math-Inline Formula"

```
 \newcommand{\kon}{k_\text{on}}
 \kon
```

When I compile the document using "View PDF" I get this error

```
 Undefined control sequence
 Description:
  $\kon
      $
 The control sequence at the end of the top line
 of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
 misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
 spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
 and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The weirdest part is that I've used this exact macro in other LyX documents and it works fine.  If I remove the \text part, it also works fine.  What's going on?

Comment: Do you have Document > Settings... > Math Options > amsmath set to "load automatically" or "load always"?

Comment: It is preferable to place the definitions like `\newcommand{\kon}{k_\text{on}}` in your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble rather than mid-document (using Insert > TeX Code).

Comment: I think one problem might be not wrapping the `\text` part in braces: I'd expect that to result in TeX grabbing `\text` as the only thing in the subscript and then complaining about `argument of \text has an extra }`. That naturally does not explain the undefined control sequence though…

Comment: Your `\newcommand` should work only in mathmode! Add `$ .. $` and it'll work. Or modify `\newcommand{\kon}{\ensuremath{k_\text{on}}}`

Comment: @AboAmmar -- the `\newcommand` statement is okay, as long as it is in the preamble.  it's invoked in math mode properly.  what *isn't* clear is the complete content of the error message; the context is lost, and that contains information that is essential to the proper identification of what's happening here.

Comment: Thank you Werner!  I changed the settings to "load always" and it worked.  Why did I need to do that?  I don't like using the preamble so much because 1) it takes extra clicks to get there and 2) it's hidden and 3) it's harder to debug when you have to keep going back and forth.  Is there a reason it's preferable to use the preamble?  I got the same error even when I put the command there.

Comment: Btw `\text` is not the propper macro in the context, it is for textual comments in displayed math, not for making indices upright . Use `\textup` or `\textnormal`.  Additionally, it is shear luck that `_\text{on} ` works, better to always use brakes on the argument for`_`

Comment: Daleif, when you say \text isn't proper, can you say what the practical negative consequences are of using \text? Also, I don't know what you mean by "use brakes"

Comment: (1) misspelling, use braces. (2) use `\text` in an italic context, for example in a displayed formula inside a theorem. Then `\text`'s output is also italic as it is supposed to be used for textual comments (as I mentioned). It is also not to be used for things like `\text{Log} ` to get that upright, again for the very same reason. Sadly there are a lot of people misusing `\text` like this. It is in my top 3 of the most common latex error in the manuscripts I've edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to be loaded in order to use `\text`. And the default setting for LyX is to "load [it] automatically". However, this automated loading requires you to use some `amsmath`-related environment (see Insert > AMS *), and unfortunately defining `\text` in a `\newcommand` doesn't invoke this loading.

You can change this choice so that `amsmath` is "load[ed] always" via Document > Settings... > Math Options > `amsmath` > "load always":

[image]

Note that LaTeX, like most programming languages, provides some form of scope to its definitions. So, if you Insert > TeX Code somewhere inside a `table` (just as an example) with the code being `\newcommand{\kon}{k_\text{on}}`, that macro - `\kon` - will only have a limited scope *within* the `table` environment. That's why it is usually best to insert definitions inside the Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble. Alternatively, you can always create your own definitions in a separate `.sty`le or `.inc` file that you include.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, I assume you forgot to add `\usepackage{amsmath}` or its extended `\usepackage{mathtools}` in the preamble. Using the `\text{ .. }` command requires either of these packages.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\kon}{k_\text{on}}
\begin{document}

$\kon$

\end{document}
```

[image]

But, when removing `\usepackage{mathtools}`, the following error message appears (which is the same as yours):

```
\kon ->k_\text
{on}
l.6 $\kon
$
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```